# I cant add a "showDetails" (beginner) (addeventlisteners)

Tags: javascript, function, command, addeventlistener, event-listener

I have a very basic question which I just cant seem to work it out

I just want to basically create a function that will showDetails when I click in an **object** from a list which is called **"pokemonList"**

Nothing I do creates a function to what I need to do which is the object having a response after being clicked:

the part of the code in the question is:

.

```
`function eventListener(button, pokemon) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    showDetails(pokemon);
  });

}

///////////this following part is incorrect, it needs to make the ''showDetails'' be responsive and ///////////show the pokemon(object) name.  Please help me as I'm stuck and I've tried many things

**function showDetails(pokemon) { 
  eventListener("button");
  console.log(pokemon);
}**

///////////////

pokemonList.forEach(function(pokemon) {
  let pokemonList = document.querySelector(".pokemon-list");
  let listItem = document.createElement("li");
  let button = document.createElement("button");
  button.innerText = pokemon.name;
  button.classList.add("stylez");
  listItem.appendChild(button);
  pokemonList.appendChild(listItem);




});`
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment `showDetails` calls `eventListener` which calls `showDetails` which calls `eventListener` etc - which is bad.

So ideally you want to

1. Cache the list element first.
2. Using [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) assign one listener to that element that can catch events from its child elements when they're fired and "bubble up" the DOM.
3. To minimise the adverse affects of repeatedly updating the DOM within your loop create [a document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) which you can append new elements, and which - post loop - you can append to the list element.
4. `showDetails` will handle the events from the list listener. In this example it checks to see if the child element that fired the event is a button, and then logs the text content of the button - but obviously you can change that to update a separate element etc.

```js
// Cache the list element, and add a listener to it.
const list = document.querySelector('.pokemon-list');
list.addEventListener('click', showDetails);

const pokemonList = [
  { name: 'Bob' },
  { name: 'Ron' },
  { name: 'Sue' },
  { name: 'Jane' }
];

// Check that the child element that fired
// the event is a button, and log its text content
function showDetails(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
  }
}

// Create a document fragment
const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

// Loop over the array and for each object
// add create a list item, and a button, append the button
// to the list item, and then the list item to the fragment
pokemonList.forEach(pokemon => {
  const listItem = document.createElement('li');
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = pokemon.name;
  button.classList.add('stylez');
  listItem.appendChild(button);
  frag.appendChild(listItem);
});

// Finally append the fragment of list items
// to the cached list element
list.appendChild(frag);
```

```css
.stylez { background-color: lightgreen; }
```

```html
<ul class="pokemon-list" />
```

Comment: thank you so much Andy, with all these comments about what you did makes it even more simple to understand. 

I just have one doubt about this one, why do you add an "e.target" ,e.g;

***function showDetails(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
  } ***

does this 'e' stands for event.target ? or is it just a parameter I gotta use? thanks!

Comment: Yes. When the listener calls the handler it passes the event (which I called `e`) as an argument. `target` refers to the element that fired the event, but there are lots of other attributes.method available depending on the event that was fired (click event, keyboard event, mouse event etc.) [Here's some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event). @maza